# Get data attribute by looping through index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through a set of elements and get their data-color attribute based on which index they have. However, it tell me that item.data is undefined. What is the proper way to do this?

```
leng = $('.item').length;
for (i = 0; i < leng; i++){
    var item = $('.item').get(i);
    var data = item.data('color');

}
```

Comment: Could you post a link to JSFiddle or create a snippet with the rest of your code?

Comment: Why you don't use `$('.item').each()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".item").each(function () {
  var data = $(this).data("color");
});
```

or

```
$(".item").each(function () {
  var data = $(this).attr("data-color");
});
```

Comment: you can remove my first option, alex has already given it! refreshed page after posting : )

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use  jquery .[**each()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$(".item").each(function () {
  var data = $(this).data("color");
});
```

Assuming you want to keep this values somewhere, alternative you can use [**.map()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
var data = $(".item").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("color");
}).get();

console.log(data); //["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="item" data-color="green"></div>
<div class="item" data-color="yellow"></div>
<div class="item" data-color="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

by `get()` you try to access HTML element, but `.data()` is a jQuery function. Try the following with `.eq()` which returns a jQuery object:

```
leng = $('.item').length;
for (i = 0; i < leng; i++){
    var item = $('.item').eq(i);
    var data = item.data('color');

}
```